Pyside6 QTableView: how to sort column with a QCheckBox?
I have a QTableView containing a column with checkboxes. Now I want to sort this column.
But as soon as I set a QSortFilterProxyModel as table model, the checkbox is no more shown.
What must I do that this works?
With QSortFilterProxyModel:

Without QSortFilterProxyModel:

The code is based on another example for a centered checkbox and is without using the QSortFilterProxyModel.
Change the line self.table_view.setModel(table_model) to self.table_view.setModel(proxy_model) to show the behaviour.
import sys
import pandas as pd
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, Property, Signal, QAbstractTableModel
from PySide6.QtCore import QSortFilterProxyModel
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QCheckBox, QHBoxLayout, QStyledItemDelegate, QTableView, QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow


class CenterCheckBox(QWidget):
    toggled = Signal(bool)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.check = QCheckBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.check, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.check.setFocusProxy(self)
        self.check.toggled.connect(self.toggled)
        # set a 0 spacing to avoid an empty margin due to the missing text
        self.check.setStyleSheet('color: red; spacing: 0px;')
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

    @Property(bool, user=True)   # note the user property parameter
    def checkState(self):
        return self.check.isChecked()

    @checkState.setter
    def checkState(self, state):
        self.check.setChecked(state)


class MyCheckboxDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        check = CenterCheckBox(parent)
        check.toggled.connect(lambda: self.commitData.emit(check))
        return check

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.checkState)


class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        print(data)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, index=None):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole or role == Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole:
                if self._data.columns[index.column()]=='Delete':
                    return ''
                value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
                return str(value)


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args)
        table_model = TableModel(pd.DataFrame([['1', '1'], ['0', '0']]))
        self.table_view = QTableView()
        proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        proxy_model.setSourceModel(table_model)
        self.table_view.setModel(table_model)
        self.table_view.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.table_view.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, MyCheckboxDelegate(self))
        for row in range(0, table_model.rowCount()):
            self.table_view.openPersistentEditor(table_model.index(row, 0))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_view)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MyWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())


The index used in views must belong to the same model: if you use a different model, you need to use that model to get the index. Change the loop declaration to for row in range(proxy_model.rowCount()): and the openPersistentEditor() argument to proxy_model.index(row, 0). In reality, a more appropriate solution is to always get the model dynamically, so: model = self.table_view.model(), then for row in range(model.rowCount()): and model.index(row, 0). Finally, don't use comments to point out errors in your post, use the [edit] link at the bottom of the post instead.

So, I also have to use the model dynamically if it is set a few lines before?

Haven't found an edit link, and there was no more time to search. And, it's my first post here.


You're welcome; 2. You need to use it dynamically only if you need it to be dynamic, which is the basic principle of dynamicality: if your view will always use the proxy, then just use the proxy; if, otherwise, the view may change its model at runtime, then use the model() function; 3. we know it's your first post, and for that very reason you should take your time to carefully check the website UI: a simple text search for "edit" with your browser would show that edit link just under your post; rushing a question doesn't help anybody, not even you. Remember: this is not a help desk.


Please take your time to read [ask] and review the checklist. Be aware that the main purpose of StackOverflow is to be a collection of knowledge, so, while we may help you with your question, we post answers (and questions) for everybody. A good question is not posted in a rush, but carefully written. It may take some time, but the only way to get good answers is by asking questions that are properly put. I've written some questions on my own here that took me days to be properly finalized, and I know for sure that I'm not the only one.
